# How to make variables from firebase database global in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Locations');

    rootRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
             lat = snapshot.child('latitude').val();
             longi = snapshot.child('longitude').val();
             console.log(snapshot.child('latitude').val());
          }, function (error) {
             console.log("Error: " + error.code);
   });
```

When i console.log(lat); lat is undefined.
I am new to javascript. Is there any way it can be globally available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Do you console.log it inside the callback function or after that?

Comment: Show us more context. Right now, it looks like you forgot to declare the variables using either `var`, `let` or `const`.

Comment: @Mulperi  outside the callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ***console.log(lat)*** that is not shown on your snippet is outside the callback function and runs before the callback when ***lat*** is still undefined. You need to do whatever you want to do with it, inside the callback when it is available.

Read this article to get to understand callback functions a little better:
https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

I hope this was any help to you!

Comment: Thank you so much. that worked however  the value is not updating asynchronous.  I thought firebase is real time. I had to refresh the browser to update. Any pointer on that ?

Comment: nvm. i figured it out